# Exception occured in published windows application regarding with Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser"

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on windows application in which I need to execute some SQL script through programming.

For that I'm using the assembly *Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.100.0.0*

Here is my code

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Executes the script query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The connection string.</param>
    /// <param name="dbScriptData">The database script data.</param>
    private void ExecuteScriptQuery(string connectionString, string dbScriptData)
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("DB Setup: script execution start");

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        //-- create SQL Server instance ---
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(dbScriptData); // execute sql script
    }
```

Same code works good in debug mode. when I publish this code and install its `.exe` on same machine its works there as well.

But when install that `.exe` on another machine, I get the exception at the time of script execution.

Here is the exception I captured in logs.

> Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The tool used to build Windows app is Visual Studio 2019, and I'm using:

- .NET Framework 4.6
- Platform target: "Any CPU" with prefer 32bit checkbox kept unchecked
- The method used to publish - ClickOnce

**Edit 1:**

I made it compulsory to user to have the .NET Framework 4.6 preinstalled on their machine before installing exe setup

Comment: do you have same .net framework on both mahines?

Comment: yes, i made it compulsory to install the same framework at the time of installation

Comment: The SQL Server management support is not part of .NET Framework. It is a separate install: I suspect `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser` will be part of that extra install.

Comment: ok, I will try to make it preinstallation requirement then.

Comment: Did you add the `BatchParser` into `Prerequisites`?

Comment: no, I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient` now, used `regex` to handle `GO` command issue there